# How old is this brick?

Tags: part-identification, history

How old would you say this brick is? It has the code 2837 on the inside of it. Any info would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can find the history of almost any piece by looking it up on Bricklink.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like part of [the old 9-Volt motor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2838c01&idColor=9) that was made from 1990 and 2002.

[image]

The full thing's part number is listed as 2838 which I assume is the mold ID stamped on dark grey base, while 2837 is the mold ID of the top part.

I don't think it's supposed to come apart, it looks like there are 4 clips on each sides which have been broken off of your piece.

Comment: Had a few of these, definitely wasn’t supposed to come apart.

Comment: Broken and buried in the ground from the looks of it.  Or is that grease from the motor the inside is crusted with?

Comment: Definitely broken: in the bottom view, you can see where all eight of the tabs that held the motor housing together have broken off.

Comment: Thanks guys. It had been in the dirt. I didn't recognize the shape at all and the hollowness of it made me speculate it may be old. Broken housing makes sense. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Tyler, it sounds like you agree with this answer.  If so, it would be nice to click the checkbox beside it to show that you accept it.  Since you asked the question you are the only one with this power.

Answer (score -2):

Your brick appears to be the housing of the motor for the Lego Technic Dune Buggy, and may be upwards of 30 years old.

Comment: Buggy aka RC Motor is totally different motor.

Comment: The one I have is identical to the above-pictured.  Don't make me find it!

Comment: Do you happen to know which set exactly you are referring to? 8475 or 8284 maybe? I don't see any "Buggy" sets with a motor mentioned in another answer.

Comment: @Alex Hi, I cannot provide exact clarification for you.  Might edit to include uncertainty?  Meh.  Focusing purely on the title of question, I would maintain the second half of my submitted answer.